# putting methods in base class that doesnt make sense/belong there

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, design-principles

I've been lately thinking over design principles and patterns and a question did strike me.

Let us say, I want to design a racing game. I want to design the classes for a variety of cars.

- each car may have different feature
- the most common features can be put in the base class - 'Car'

Now, I learned that you should always strive to work with abstractions.

All the code that tries to manipulate the car will try to call the abstract methods on `Car` like `Car.Accelerate()`, `Car.TurnLeft()`, etc...

But what about the specific features? Like some cars might have rocket thrusters or a parachute and you might want to use them (I know this sounds ridiculous, but my point here is 'There might be special features in derived classes that might not justify the actual type(or base type) of that specific class')?

So, what about them?

Would you rather raise few more abstract methods in base class making it less cohesive, or would you put some if blocks and type casts (to get the actual class object and use that method) making it more coupled?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.  UseRockets() would probably be in the derived class RocketCar, while Turn(degrees) might be in the base class Car.  Shared stuff goes in the base class, particular stuff doesn't.  What are you missing?

Comment: @Dan how does this UseRockets() get used ?  

   you could do two things
   1. put UseRockets() as abstract method in base class, let derived classes provide their implementation

   Car car = Factory.GetCar(carTYpe);
   car.UseRockets();
   2. Car car = Factory.GetCar(carTYpe);
   if (IsRocketPowered(carType))
   {
      ((RocketPoweredCar)car).UseRockets();
   }

Answer (score 2):

Try to think of it the other way around: If you had to drive from A to B and you didn't care about the roads you use or the time you get there, you might just take a `Car`, `Accelerate()` it, and `Stop()` whenever you're there. So, an abstract kind of `Car` will easily suffice for the purpose. I imagine many people would use that `Car` while they don't actually care for the details.

But then there are circumstances where you actually need speed. You need a rocket booster in order to arrive in time. So what you do, is not get some `Car` but a `RocketBoostedCar`. It'll provide you means to `AccelerateWayFaster()` than other cars and, well, there you go - pretty fast.

My point is: if you actually need special features that an abstract can't deliver, you already know that you have a concrete (special) object. You probably asked for it (using its constructor, or telling a factory to produce a special kind). And if you have that "special" `Car`, you can use its special features.

Comment: In fact, in one case, you might have a handle to Car. In the other case, instead of casting and if conditions, your code may actually reference (and thus compile time bind to) RocketBoostedCar. This will ensure that whenever that code is called, it can only be called with this particular type, avoiding any run time failures. There might be a case where you might not care, but want the car to use all its acceleration. Well, then RocketBoostedCar should just Accelerate() using its rocket boosters.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about design right now.  Your idea for the system is too ill-formed to decide on low-level design details like class inheritance.  Instead decide on some exact use cases and implement them.  Then implement some more use cases.  Continuously refactor the code to eliminate duplication.  Introduce interfaces to eliminate circular dependencies.  When it starts getting messy and you aren't sure how to proceed, then you can post code to stackoverflow.

After you get considerable practice coding, then you will be able to visualize more of the implementation earlier in the process.